# How can I specify the url address in Asp.NET MVC redirect-to-action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

Is there a way in MVC to specify the browser url address after doing a redirect-to-action? In my code, I have

```
RedirectToAction("myaction", "mycontroller", new {arg1= "height", arg2="weight"})
```

The address that shows up in the browser is:

```
http/mywebsite/mycontroller/myaction?arg1=height&arg2=weight
```

What I want to appear in the browser url, however, is:

```
http://mywebsite/height/weight
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Which language & MVC framework are you using?

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a specific route to acheive this, simply add a MapRoute to your application start in Global.asax.cs :

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("myRouteName",
        "/{height}/{weight}",
        new { controller = "mycontroller", action = "myaction" },
        new[] { "Namespace.Of.My.Controller" });
}
```

Comment: Kronos, thanks much for the answer. My application is more complicated. My application allows users to create virtual resources such as the height/weight example I have. I really cannot predefine what they might define, therefore, height/weight was only one example. It could  be numerous more, height1/weight1, etc. (All these virtual resources map the same internal resources but I do no want the users to see them). I really cannot hardcode such a list with MapRoute. Whatever the solution, it needs to be flexible at run time. Please let me know if you have any ideas. -thx

Comment: I believe you can map routes dynamicaly anytime during your application life cycle as do many MVC based CMS.

Comment: I understand you want clean URL's but I don't think rewriting URL is a good way to go. It will bring you a new set of issues. You will for example maybe have to read those URL back, and in my humble opition it's mostly rebuilding a MVC routing system on top of an existing one. Or maybe I simply do not understand what you would like, good luck :)

Comment: Krons, the application is very complex. Is there a way I can simply set the url when I create the Response object? I know I have access to this object, not sure if I can change that.

Comment: I use ASP.NET MVC since version 1 and as far as I know, the two only types of "rewriting" are : 1 routing, 2 redirect (301, 302,...). Redirect = routing anyway because if user refresh the page you expect that the server routes the request again to the right resource. I'm out of ideas sorry, wish you best of luck :)